# Issue with the z-index

Tags: html, css, position, z-index

I am developing a web project in which I have a problem with z-index. The following code simply shows my problem.
When I move the yellow box to right it goes under the next blue box.
I changed z-index and position but it didn't work.
how can I fix it?
the code is here:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

<head>
  <title>Untitled</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div style="background-color:red; width: 500px; height: 500px; position:absolute; z-index: 9;">

        <div style="background-color:green; width: 400px; height: 400px; position:absolute; z-index: 99;">
            <div style="background-color:blue;width: 100px; height: 100px; display:inline-block; position:relative; z-index: 999;">


            </div>
             <div style="background-color:blue; width: 100px; height: 100px; display:inline-block; position:relative; z-index: 999;">

                <div style=" background-color:yellow; width: 50px; height: 50px;  display:block; position:relative; left: 70px; z-index: 9999999;"></div>
            </div>
             <div style="background-color:blue; width: 100px; height: 100px; display:inline-block; position:relative;z-index: 999;">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You should give an example of what you tried to do.

Comment: Why don't you use classes?

Answer (score 1):

The yellow box is already inside of a blue box, and when it move to right it will under the next blue box, i put a z-index value on the blue box which contain the yellow box. so it can above the next blue box.

```
<div style="background-color:red; width: 500px; height: 500px; position:absolute; ">

<div style="background-color:green; width: 400px; height: 400px; position:absolute; ">
    <div style="background-color:blue;width: 100px; height: 100px; display:inline-block; position:relative;">


    </div>
    <div style="background-color:blue; width: 100px; height: 100px; display:inline-block; position:relative;z-index: 10;">

        <div style=" background-color:yellow; width: 50px; height: 50px;  display:block; position:relative; left: 70px;"></div>
    </div>
    <div style="background-color:blue; width: 100px; height: 100px; display:inline-block; position:relative;">

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please explain what you did? What's the solution you're proposing, and why?

Comment: Armin - The yellow box is already inside of a blue box, and when it move to right it will under the next blue box, i put a z-index value on the blue box which contain the yellow box. so it can above the next blue box

Comment: Thank you for explanation. Can you please make it part of your answer? Your answer should contain not only "try it" code, but also an explanation of what you are doing and why. This will be useful for the asker, and anyone who might find your answer in the future.

Comment: I edited the code and inserted the z-index. now without deleting the z-index what's the solution?

Comment: put 9999 z-index value on the blue box which contain the yellow box

Answer (score -2):

Just set a z-index value for the div, which is containing the yellow background. You may have a quick look at the output of the following code snippet. I set "z-index: 99;" to that div.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

<head>
  <title>Untitled</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div style="background-color:red; width: 500px; height: 500px; position:absolute; ">

        <div style="background-color:green; width: 400px; height: 400px; position:absolute; ">
            <div style="background-color:blue;width: 100px; height: 100px; display:inline-block; position:relative;">


            </div>
             <div style="background-color:blue; width: 100px; height: 100px; display:inline-block; position:relative;">

                <div style=" background-color:yellow; width: 50px; height: 50px;  display:block; position:relative; left: 70px; z-index: 99;"></div>
            </div>
             <div style="background-color:blue; width: 100px; height: 100px; display:inline-block; position:relative;">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you please explain what you did? What's the solution you're proposing, and why?

Comment: It's quite simple. Just added z-index. Moreover, I've added the snippet to show the result in a quick look.

Comment: Can you please add explanation to your answer?

Comment: Added with the answer. 
Thanks.